# Erro com String utilizando o método nextLine() em Java

Tags: java, string, orientação-a-objetos, netbeans, char

Eu tô com um problema em um programa simples em java.
Quando eu executo e faço o scanner com String, ele simplesmente passa direto para o final do programa, mas quando eu coloco char ele não passa e executa normalmente, mesmo assim eu queria executar com strings e não com char[image: Uma imagem do que acontece]. 
Esse é o código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String resp;
        int op;

        do{
        System.out.println("////////////////////BANCO/////////////////////////////");
        System.out.println("O que deseja?"+
                "\n[1]Para criar uma nova conta;"+
                "\n[2]Para sair.");
        op = in.nextInt();

        switch(op){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Você deseja criar uma nova conta? [s/n]");
                resp = in.nextLine();
                if(resp.equals("s")){
                    Conta c1 = new Conta();
                    System.out.println("\n---------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Tipo da conta: ");
                    c1.abrirConta(in.nextLine());

                    System.out.println("\n[1]Para depositar;"+
                            "\n[2]Para sacar;"+
                            "\n[3]Para pagar mensalidade;"+
                            "\n[4]Para fechar conta;"+
                            "\n[5]Para sair.");
                    int op2 = in.nextInt();

                    switch(op2){
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("Quanto você deseja depositar?");
                            c1.depositar(in.nextFloat());

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("Quanto você deseja sacar?");
                            c1.sacar(in.nextFloat());
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("Você deseja pagar a mensalidade? [s/n]");
                            String resp2 = in.nextLine();
                            if(resp2.equals("s")){
                            c1.pagarMensal();
                            }else if(resp2.equals("n")){
                                break;}
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println("Você deseja fechar essa conta? [s/n]");
                            String resp3 =in.nextLine();
                            if(resp3.equals("s")){
                                c1.fecharConta();
                            }else if(resp3.equals("n")){break;}
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            System.out.println("Você deseja sair? [s/n]");
                            String resp4 = in.nextLine();
                            if(resp4.equals("s")){
                                break;
                            }else if(resp4.equals("n")){
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Você deseja sair? [s/n]");
                String resp5 = in.nextLine();
                if(resp5.equals("s")){
                    break;
                }else if(resp5.equals("n")){

                }
            }
        }while(op == 2);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o `next();` no lugar do `nextLine();`.

Fiz um teste, tentei replicar seu código, apenas sem os métodos da classe `Conta`. Ele rodou até o final de acordo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String resp;
    int op;

    do{
    System.out.println("////////////////////BANCO/////////////////////////////");
    System.out.println("O que deseja?"+
            "\n[1]Para criar uma nova conta;"+
            "\n[2]Para sair.");
    op = in.nextInt();

    switch(op){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Você deseja criar uma nova conta? [s/n]");
            resp = in.next();
            if(resp.equals("s")){
                System.out.println("Sim");

                int op2 = in.nextInt();

                switch(op2){
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Selecionado 1");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Selecionado 2");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Você deseja pagar a mensalidade? [s/n]");
                        String resp2 = in.next();
                        if(resp2.equals("s")){
                        System.out.println("Pagar mensalidade");
                        }else if(resp2.equals("n")){
                            break;}
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("Você deseja fechar essa conta? [s/n]");
                        String resp3 =in.next();
                        if(resp3.equals("s")){
                            System.out.println("Fechado");
                        }else if(resp3.equals("n")){break;}
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        System.out.println("Você deseja sair? [s/n]");
                        String resp4 = in.next();
                        if(resp4.equals("s")){
                            break;
                        }else if(resp4.equals("n")){
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Você deseja sair? [s/n]");
            String resp5 = in.next();
            if(resp5.equals("s")){
                break;
            }else if(resp5.equals("n")){

            }
        }
    }while(op != 2);
}
```

O while está declarado errado também, correto seria `while(op != 2)` como foi observado. O erro que você descreveu creio que não tem a ver com isso diretamente, com o `nextLine();` a aplicação realmente pula a linha.

Parece que isso acontece pq você está lendo o próximo inteiro primeiramente com o `nextInt()`, só que o usuário além de escrever um número ele tem que dar um ENTER para validar a entrada. Esse enter é na verdade um caractere \n, portanto como vc leu apenas o inteiro esse \n vai ficar no buffer de entrada. Logo, a sua próxima instrução `nextLine()` vai consumir este \n

Comment: Pode apagar os seus comentários para limpar esta secção e não confundir.

Comment: Agora funcionou! Obrigado!